# Invalid signed request

Tags: facebook, session, cookies, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-login

I have a site that uses Facebook API to sign in. We're using the JS SDK and the C# SDK.

Our site has been working fine for about a month, but last night people started getting blank pages when they signed in.

This also happened once during beta testing but we figured it was because some changes we did in the Facebook log in process and it disappeared after we deleted our cookies. But now it has happened again and I can't ask my users to delete their cookies (for some it seems to help just by restarting the browser, still very annoying though)

In my error log I can see the error which is as follows:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid signed request.
    at Facebook.FacebookSignedRequest.TryParse(String secret, String signedRequestValue, Int32 maxAge, Double currentTime, Boolean throws)
    at Facebook.FacebookSignedRequest.Parse(String secret, String signedRequestValue)
    at Facebook.FacebookSignedRequest.GetSignedRequest(String appId, String appSecret, HttpContextBase httpContext)
    at Facebook.FacebookSession.GetSession(String appId, String appSecret, HttpContextBase httpContext, FacebookSignedRequest signedRequest)
    at Facebook.Web.FacebookWebContext.get_Session()
    at Facebook.Web.FacebookWebContext.IsAuthenticated()
    at Facebook.Web.FacebookWebContext.IsAuthorized(String[] permissions)
    at Facebook.Web.Mvc.FacebookAuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext, IFacebookApplication facebookApplication)
    at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
    at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
    at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
    at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
    at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

The strange thing is that it happened over night for several users at the same time, I've been logging in and out of the page everyday for about a month and today I just get a blank page and this error shows in the log.

Obviously it looks like it has something to do with the cookie or losing the session. It seems to happen to people that doesn't sign out of Facebook, that stay signed in and then come back at a later time and perhaps have lost their session, and when they sign in again it doesn't work. I can't confirm it 100% but it also seems like the error happens for a lot of people that keeps the actual site open in their browser and just let their computer go into sleep mode and then the next day when they start navigating the site again they get a blank page, so they go to the sign in page, try to log in but after logging in get a blank page again.

So you could say that is whats causing the error but why does it happen to everyone on the same day and not to someone every now and then? That doesn't make sense to me.

The signup JS looks like this:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
        channelUrl: 'http://www.xxxxxx.com/channel.html',
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        oauth: true, // enable OAuth 2.0
        xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Run js that is dependent on the Facebook session
    initFacebook(); 

    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();

};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
} (document));
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using official C# SDK (which is [deprecated](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/624/)) or the [opensource C# SDK hosted on codeplex](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: I'm using the one hosted on Codeplex (through NuGet)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to redundant cookies from Facebook. I've posted a [question here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835255/facebook-c-sharp-sdk-invalid-signed-request-exception-when-parsing-fbsr-cooki) and an [issue report on Facebook C# SDK's codeplex website](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/workitem/5927) where I explain the cause of the problem and show the exact spot in the SDK's code where the exception is thrown. Hope to gather some attention because the issue is pretty serious and probably due to FB's OAuth 2.0 implementation.

Answer (score 0):

We are discontinuing support of parsing cookies in the Facebook C# SDK. Facebook no longer recommends that developers or SDKs attempt to read the cookies directly. We will provide more documentation and guidance on this on the Facebook C# SDK documentation (http://docs.csharpsdk.org) in the near future.

See details about Facebook's recommendation for not using cookies here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/624/