# Facebook C# SDK: "Invalid signed request" exception when parsing fbsr cookie

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've posted an issue on the Facebook C# SDK website, the problem statement and all the details can be found there: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/workitem/5927
Please help me :(

Comment: Vote for this bug https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/359391590741517

Comment: Voted, please vote for the bug on C# SDK side: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/workitem/5927

Answer (score 0):

This may be just a simple answer, but have you tried deleting the cookies of your browser? I was having the same problem and deleting the cookies solved it.

Update: Nop sorry, this makes this work just the firts time, when I request a page again I get the "Invalid signed request".

Comment: Yep, I've tried that too and the two cookies are recreated at next init/login cycle. The only thing that works is logging out of facebook, closing and reopening the browser window, but it just works the first time: when the page is reloaded, FB creates the double fbsr cookie again and the C# SDK crashes.

Comment: Have you tried now, it seems the facbook folks solved the problem or somethig, because it's working fine for me now

Comment: @lencinhaus - could you add your app to the bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/359391590741517? This would help us look into this issue.
Please specify that you are seing double cookies set, one for subdomain and one for base domain (if this is the case).

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by setting cookie: 'yourbasedomain' instead of cookie: true in init.

Comment: I followed your advice (putting the domain in the cookie config) but I'm still having the problem.
In FB.init i use cookie: 'my.domain.com'
The application is configured with domain 'my.domain.com'.
After deleting the cookies, the application works for a while, but at some point the double cookie is created again. In my case, i have two couples of fbsr/fbm cookies, one for domain '.my.domain.com' and one for '.domain.com'.
Follow the discussion on fb and the issue report above too for updates.

Answer (score 0):

We are discontinuing support of parsing cookies in the Facebook C# SDK. Facebook no longer recommends that developers or SDKs attempt to read the cookies directly. We will provide more documentation and guidance on this on the Facebook C# SDK documentation (http://docs.csharpsdk.org) in the near future.

See details about Facebook's recommendation for not using cookies here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/624/